# How do I debug an unresponsive .Net Service when "break all" does not respond?

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, memory-leaks, crash

We have a **WCF Service Application** consuming a large amount of memory (see my other ticket today at: [Server is leaking memory; but process looks fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584626/server-is-leaking-memory-but-process-looks-fine)).

After extensive use of the Windows Service Application at a sudden moment the whole service crashes. During this moment:

- The log (WCF-Trace/Server DB Log) does display activity, but no leads.
- The memory is high, but no out of memory exception [Server is leaking memory; but process looks fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584626/server-is-leaking-memory-but-process-looks-fine)
- Number of open connections; just before 'the crash': 10 - 20
  The memory dump shows 8 threads, without an interesting stack trace. These are only small stacks, without any user code (only calls in **Microsoft-symbols**)

Can do:

- Attach the Remote Debugger;
- Connect to the port WCF is listing to;

Can't do:

- Remote Debugger; Break all does not respond
- Attach **SciTechMemoryProfiler** (exception: `0x80007002`)
- Response to any call of WCF;

The memory is still completely in use, but the server is completely unresponsive.

Comment: How many connections were open to the service? Hundreds? Does the service perform long-running operations before returning a response to clients?

Comment: Hi henginy, added additional information.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I guess the situation is not what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for reading this ticket.

We found the solution. We analyzed the dump file with **WinDebug**, and found a single function in the dump. We don't know if it was luck or expected behaviour for a **Windows Service in .Net** , but from there we were able to replicate the issue.

Thanks all for reading, and hopefully you can make progress with this 'solution'.